# How can setup automatic word wrapping for apex inputField or apex inputText?

Tags: apex, visualforce, inputfield, inputtext

I try to use a apex inputField or apex inputText Control, but the Text is shown still centered and in one single Line/Row.

What do i have to change that the Text starts from the Left-Top-Side and does the automatic word wrapping when the width of the control is reached.

Thanks for Support

Answer (score 2):

Using apex:inputTextarea fix my Problem.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_inputTextarea.htm